# Python index slicing

Tags: python-2.7

I am running the following code

```
my_list = [9, 8, 7]
for k in range (3):
    my_list.insert(-k, k+1)
print(my_list)
```

output

> `[1,9,8,3,2,7]`

but my output is

> `[1,9,8,7,3,2]`

How 7 is coming at the end?

Comment: Please reformat the code so it is readable

Comment: You'll find this useful: http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 0):

Because `list.insert (index, value)` inserts `value` *before* the value at `index`. And since an index of `-1` point to the last element of the list. So all your inserts (with an negative) index will insert before the last element.

Answer (score 0):

this is how the list changed with the three times insert

1,9,8,7

1,9,8,2,7

1,9,8,3,2,7